# How can dynamically setContentView Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-intent, setcontentview

I've to dynamically set an xml into a ContentView?

This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        value = extras.getString("ID_position");
        Log.e("TESTVALUE", value);
    }


    if (value.equals("0")){
    setContentView(R.layout.list_mobile);
    }
    if (value.equals("1")){
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog1);
    }
}
```

It crash at activity open... pls help me ^^

PS: the value is correct ;)

EDIT: i've done a big mistake in extend class... damned copy and paste... i'm sorry again ;) now it work well

Comment: post the error please

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, the possible reason is:

Value at the `Bundle` with id = `ID_position` has type other than `String` => `value` will be `null` and you'll get `NPE` at `value.equals()`. Are you sure you didn't put `int` instead?

Comment: getIntent does not return null